# output update of ROBOT_POSE_EKF is 5 sec. Can I get them faster?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Question 1.. Can I just use wheel odometry data and imu data and get effective kalman updated data using robot_pose_ekf package?Is there any package which is more handy which I overlooked?

Question 2..
The output of /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined is same as the /pose published by wheel odometry. Do I have to make any changes?

Question3..Message update rate is around 5 sec and can I decrease it ?

I tried changing the freq parameter in robot_pose_ekf.launch from 30 hz to 120 hz but the update comes around once in 5 sec.

Sometimes the output does not start immediately.

nutan@nutan-laptop:~$ rostopic hz /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined

subscribed to [/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined]

average rate: 0.018

```
min: 55.560s max: 55.560s std dev: 0.00000s window: 2
```

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

average rate: 0.033

```
min: 5.054s max: 55.560s std dev: 25.25297s window: 3
```

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

average rate: 0.046

```
min: 5.053s max: 55.560s std dev: 23.80890s window: 4
```

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

average rate: 0.057

```
min: 5.053s max: 55.560s std dev: 21.86982s window: 5
```

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

average rate: 0.066

```
min: 5.053s max: 55.560s std dev: 20.20241s window: 6
```

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

no new messages

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44452/output-update-of-robot_pose_ekf-is-5-sec.-can-i-get-them-faster?/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally after three days, found the answer...

First the error was

"Could not transform the imu messages from /base_imu to /base_footprint"

This was found from the rxconsole output.

TF tree was connected.

It was solved by changing the (/base_imu)frame id of IMU to /base_footprint

Thats it...:)

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-10-01**:
Glad you solved the problem.  Would you mind marking the answer as accepted?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-03**:
did that

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-01-22**:
This helped me figure out why EKF's update rate was incorrect. Just like in your case, the EKF node was complaining about the IMU messages not having base_footprint IDs. After specifying "base_footprint" for the "frame_id" param for the IMU node, the EKF node's rate increased to 5Hz - our GPS rate

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-01-28**:
its nice that you posted back saying that this was useful